# Postfix - SASL PLAIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I set up an email server using Cyberpanel (which uses dovecot + postfix internally). I have some ticketing software hooked up to the email server that bulk sends emails (currently trying to send around 90~ at once to those who have purchased tickets) but around half way through the logs, I get the error in the title. I have searched across the internet and struggled to find people with the exact error, and definitely not in the same scenario as me.

```
    Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtp[1615]: 5443BC09A2: to=<blahblah@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[66.102.1.26]:25, delay=0.99, delays=0.1/0/0.16/0.73, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1666101970 o5-20020a5d6485000000b0022adfca5d94si9257343wri.812 - gsmtp)
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[1170]: 5443BC09A2: removed
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtp[1599]: D72D2C0946: to=<blahblah@cam.ac.uk>, relay=mx.cam.ac.uk[131.111.8.149]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.09/0/0.08/1.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1oknEP-000Mm7-bb)
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[1170]: D72D2C0946: removed
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1444]: 5F32AC0946: client=unknown[138.68.169.127], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=blahblah@selwynsnowball.co.uk
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/cleanup[1592]: 5F32AC0946: message-id=<4b5c8d7c-3873-2c2b-8c4d-682cbef4e455@selwynsnowball.co.uk>
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[1170]: 5F32AC0946: from=<blahblah@selwynsnowball.co.uk>, size=2571, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1444]: disconnect from unknown[138.68.169.127] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 commands=5
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1433]: 9944EC0997: client=unknown[138.68.169.127], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=blahblah@selwynsnowball.co.uk
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/cleanup[1633]: 9944EC0997: message-id=<d4f1ba58-b8b1-5ea9-222f-431309ae090e@selwynsnowball.co.uk>
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[1170]: 9944EC0997: from=<blahblah@selwynsnowball.co.uk>, size=2565, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1433]: disconnect from unknown[138.68.169.127] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 commands=5
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtp[1596]: EEC31C0B40: to=<blahblah@cam.ac.uk>, relay=mx.cam.ac.uk[131.111.8.147]:25, delay=0.83, delays=0.06/0/0.1/0.67, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1oknEQ-000kXq-Wl)
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[1170]: EEC31C0B40: removed
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1448]: warning: unknown[138.68.169.127]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1440]: warning: unknown[138.68.169.127]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1448]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[138.68.169.127]
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1448]: disconnect from unknown[138.68.169.127] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1440]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[138.68.169.127]
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1440]: disconnect from unknown[138.68.169.127] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1456]: warning: unknown[138.68.169.127]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1456]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[138.68.169.127]
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1456]: disconnect from unknown[138.68.169.127] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1468]: warning: unknown[138.68.169.127]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1468]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[138.68.169.127]
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1468]: disconnect from unknown[138.68.169.127] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1471]: warning: unknown[138.68.169.127]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1471]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[138.68.169.127]
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1471]: disconnect from unknown[138.68.169.127] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1489]: warning: unknown[138.68.169.127]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server
Oct 18 14:06:10 localhost postfix/smtps/smtpd[1489]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[138.68.169.127]
```

The former part of the logs is it working correctly, the second half is it not. I'm assuming the authentication server got overwhelmed. I've already tried increasing the number of workers to a very high value.

Comment: As a first step, put `saslauthd` into debug mode.

Comment: @Bib I've tried running saslauthd -d and it says the command is not found.

Comment: That should be run as root and on the system which it currently runs. And you need to stop what is currently running.

Comment: I was logged in as root, the command just doesn't exist. It suggests I apt install sasl2-bin. I haven't turned the email server off - but I doubt turning it off would make the command be registered in anyway.

Comment: Are you in control of `138.68.169.127`? If so, then you need to check on that system where and why sasl is failing. If not, then why are you trying to AUTH into it? A bit of advice, don't drip feed information, give as much relevant info as you can in the question.

Comment: I have never worked with sasl authentication before and this is my first time setting up an email server. I have not got access to the server on 138.68.169.127 but am the one using the ticketing software on that ip address and telling it to send emails. I've been assuming the authentication server was on the end of the email server at 139.162.246.236 and therefore trying to run saslauthd on that server. The syslog is from the server with the email server.

Comment: You need to take it up with whoever looks after `138.68.169.127`. Only they can help. Perhaps they have rate limited it.